# Overriding private final methods in Java

Tags: java

```
class X1
{
    private final void show() { ... }
}

class X2 extends X1
{
    private final void show() { ... }
}
```

**Question 1**

The code is compiling without any errors. Since the `final` keyword prevents methods from being overidden, why does the code compile?

**Question 2**

If I remove the `private` keyword from both `show` methods, the code doesn't compile as expected. Why?

Comment: see this link http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-09/02-qa-0915-private.html

Comment: good example having both final and private.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In X2, the method is not the same method, it's shadowing the method in X1. Since the method in X1 is private, X2 has no awareness of it and thus is able to reuse the method signature. So, when you have an X2 object and you call show, it will use X2's show. When you have an X1 object, it will use X1's show.

If you used the @Override annotation on X2, it would give a warning that the method to be overridden doesn't exist (or error, not 100% sure).

This is obviously not a good idea to use the same method signature as someone looking at it later could get very confused and it definitely doesn't make clear your intentions.

Comment: Since they are private, they can only be called from other methods in `X1` and `X2`. The type of the object doesn't matter but rather the context where it is called. Other methods on `X1` that call `show` on an instance of `X2` will call `X1.show`.

Comment: can u explain me the difference between shadowing and overidding.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Yes, that distinction is important to make clear.

Comment: @prerna I'm not sure what more you want me to say. Overriding means that the functionality of the super class method is subsumed by the functionality of the subclass method. So, wherever show is used when using an X2, it should use the X2 show. Shadowing means means that the subclass method only works on X2 methods that call show and the X1 show will work only on X1 methods that call show.

Comment: If this seems confusing, this should tell you why it's best to avoid shadowing unless you have some really good reason for it. Using the @Override annotation will either verify that you're overriding what you expect or alert you that something is amiss.

Comment: Overriding is done via polymorphism where a method in a subclass is called instead of the method it *overrides* in the superclass based solely on the runtime type of the object. In cases where only the declared type of a reference determines which method is called--static methods for example--there is no polymorphism and a similarly named field/method will *shadow* the item with the same name in the parent class. I would argue that with private fields and methods there is no shadowing because the item in the parent class isn't even visible to the subclass.

Comment: @prerna - Please accept AHungerArtist's answer if you feel it answered your original question.

Answer (score 1):

As they are private functions, each function belongs its own class. The `show` method in `X2` is not overriding the one `X1` as its `private`. X2 is not aware of the show method in X1. But when you remove the private classifier, X2 awares of and compiling complains.